# if else on ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am busy writing a web page for a company. I need to accomplish the following: If the output is nothing, `alert "Rookswitch is turned off"`. If the output is `"Hookswitch-Playlist"`, `alert "Rookswitch is turned on"`.
The data is grabbed from a REST API.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.0.15:8080/Cnario/REST/GetDevice?deviceName=Rook-Switch",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("De Rookswitch staat al aan");
            if (response.GetDeviceResult.DevicePins.PinValue == 'Playlist-Roken')
                handleSuccess(response);
            else
                handleError(response);
        },
        error: function(message) {
            alert("Rookswitch is uit");
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, the message is always on. even if it is off. How can i fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Are you reffering to "response"?
Also what do you mean is nothing?

Comment: And can you clarify which of the English strings in your question correlate to which of the foreign-language strings in your code?

Comment: Please show your functions `handleSuccess` and `handleError`

Comment: `staat al aan = already on` / `rook = smoke` / `is uit = is off`

Comment: It looks like you're relying on an error condition to determine if something is "off".  Why?  *Should* the server respond with an error in that case?

Comment: Ja da's goed, but I think you didn't get the concept of `success` and `error` callbacks in the first place. The `error` callback is *only* called if the REST call was unsuccessful (so it resulted in an HTTP error like 404)

Answer (score 1):

In your success function, you're doing an alert for "switched on" in all cases. No matter whether the response is blank, or contains a value.

You've put the alert for "It's switched off" in the error function. This function will only be called if the AJAX request actually fails (i.e. there is a HTTP error).

I think what you probably want to do is put an if/else block in your success function to check the value of the appropriate field in the response object to see if it contains the string "Hookswitch-Playlist" or not.

Comment: Indeed i want to put an if/else to check if it contains that string. How can i do this the best?

Comment: Well I don't know where in the response that string is held. I notice you've got another if statement in your success function to test for some different value. You just need to do the same structure, but change it so that it tests for the "Hookswitch-Playlist" string in the appropriate field within the response. e.g. if that string may appear in the "status" field in the response, then you could write `if (response.status == "Hookswitch-Playlist") { alert("on"); } else { alert ("off") }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to control the http://192.168.0.15:8080/Cnario/REST/GetDevice?deviceName=Rook-Switch response, I strongly recommend to use sth like

```
/* --------------------------------------- */
/*  Response will be generated according to which 
/*  prog lang you are using but as a result we should have sth like this
/* --------------------------------------- */

var response = {
    code: 200, // on
    message: 'Rookswitch is turned on'
}
/* OR */
var response = {
    code: 300, // off
    message: 'Rookswitch is turned off'
}

/* --------------------------------------- */
/* Response
/* --------------------------------------- */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.0.15:8080/Cnario/REST/GetDevice?deviceName=Rook-Switch",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.message);
            /* --------------------------------------- */
            /* doing sth according to server response
            /* --------------------------------------- */
            if(response.code == 200){
                /* On function goes here */
            }else if(response.code == 300){
                /* Off function goes here */
            }
        },
        error: function(message) {
            alert("Rookswitch is uit");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Too bad I am not able to change the response from the URL.